# Tumblr Photoset Frame Broken?

Tags: tumblr

```
.photoset-img { width: 200px; height: auto;}

{block:Photoset}
    {block:Photos}
        <img src="{PhotoURL-500}" class="photoset-img" />
    {/block:Photos}
{/block:Photoset}
```

This is the only way I've found to fix my photosets, but the problem is the images in the photoset are now stacked vertically atop one another instead of side by side and are taking up a lot of space on my blog. I tried setting a height, but that only stretched the pictures out individually. So, I'm at a loss. Any help you could offer would be greatly appreciated, I've been searching for a fix for this for awhile now. I've tried various suggested fixes before, but none of them work quite the way I want them to.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know they switched up how Photosets work in Tumblr semi-recently (as in in the past half a year-ish) so now you have to drag-and-drop images you upload to be side-by-side. Have you tried that?

Though, if you try that now, it's bugged so when you move it, it keeps the same height it did when it first configured it (e.g. I set my gifs for 245x138. When they're first uploaded, it shows them at 500x(whatever). When I move them to their right positions, they stay at (whatever) height but back to 245 width. I can't edit my old photoset because of this bug.

I hope both of these help if you haven't found help already. Hopefully they'll fix the height bug soon because it's really frustrating and inconvenient. It only just started, too.